# 2 .gitignore files but files can't be found

Tags: git

I have 2 `.gitignore` files.
One is placed in my home directory (`~`) and one in `~/bin`.
The `~/bin/.gitignore` file is known by the repo, but if I add the file and commit, git can't find the other files in the bin directory.

Their contents are:

```
$ cat ~/.gitignore`
*
!.gitignore
!LICENSE
!bin/
!.zsh/*
!.zshrc
$ cat ~/bin/.gitignore
composer
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the file"? `~/.gitignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the `~/.gitignore` file will be applied to all files under `~/`
- the `~/bin/.gitignore` file will be applied to all files under `~/bin/`

since `~/bin` matches both *under `~/bin/`* and *under `~/`*, both `.gitignore` files apply (the two configs are stacked unto each other).

Since your (top-level) `~/.gitignore` file contains a wildcard match `*`, this means that *all files* in `~/bin` will be ignored unless excluded (like `~/bin/.gitignore` which matches `.gitignore`)

If you what you really want is to *not ignore* all files in `~/bin` (except those listed in the (local) `~/bin/.gitignore`), you have to *unignore* them first:

```
$ cat ~/bin/.gitignore
# override wildcard match from parent gitignore
!*
# but ignore the composer file
composer
$
```